# Graphql ClientError: Variable `userId` is required

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

For a certain GraphQL request (from another endpoint) I try to use [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request/blob/master/package.json) package. I know it's not a good practice and we should add that endpoint to our federated gateway in the feature.
For the rest I use [Apollo client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) to talk to my GraphQL server and fetch data in my React app.

In my app when the user isn't logged in the `id` variable returns `null`. When the user is logged in `id` returns a `string`.

I use `useReactiveVar` from Apollo Client to get the current user id. This all works fine.

Then from the other endpoint I need below query and try to use it with `graphql-request`:

```
  const endpoint = 'https://my-endpoint/graphql';

  const query = gql`
    query($userId: String!) {
      isEligible(userId: $userId)
    }
  `;

  const variables = {
    userId: id,
  };

  request(endpoint, query, variables).then((data2) => console.log(data2));
```

But now it throws a graphql error:

> ClientError: Variable `userId` is required.:
> {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"Variable `userId` is required.

How to solve this?

Comment: I think `$userId: String!` means that the `userId` variable has to be present _and not `null`_. Try removing the exclamation mark.

Comment: @robertklep then I get the following error: `message: 'The variable `userId` is not compatible with the type of the current location.` I think the schema is defined, `userId` is non-nullable.

Comment: In that case you need to fix the schema, because you want to allow passing a `null` value.

Comment: @robertklep thanks. They only thing I don't understand. I tried also [this solution](https://www.jamalx31.com/tech-posts/using-apollo-with-multiple-graphql-endpoints), to use multiple endpoints. So only using Apollo Client. Then it just works and I don't get any error?

Comment: Are you able to confirm that userId is being passed to the context of the second endpoint? Can you also verify which version of Apollo Client is being used?